# Pass a html formatted string into the Onclik

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I  have constructed a web method that creates a html formatted string.

I want to pass the string into  my  view but doesn't work .

Can you help me with the right way to approach that problem.

```js
let table = @TMDIWebApiController.GetAssets()
let string = "<table><tr><td>AssetId</td><td>ClientId</td><td>DateOfStatement</td><td>InvestmentType</td><td>Category</td><td>Isin</td><td>IsinDescription</td><td>IsinCurrency</td><td>TradingVenue</td><td>ShareHolding</td><td>TotalIssuedShares</td><td>Notes</td><td>IsCurrent</td><td>DateTo</td><td>DateFrom</td><td>LastModified</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>test</td><td>15.12.2021 23:32:07</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>True</td><td>15.12.2021 23:32:07</td><td>15.12.2021 23:32:07</td><td>15.12.2021 23:32:07</td></tr></table>"
```

```html
<h2> Data</h2>
<p id="demo"> </p>
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerText = table'>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: `let table = @TMDIWebApiController.GetAssets()` is not normal browser client code
Also unless you want to show the HTML as HTML, you should use innerHTML but not use a `P` tag, instead use a `DIV`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2> Data</h2>
  <p id="demo"> </p>
  <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table'>Click Me!</button>

  <script>
    var table = ""

    var string = "<table><tr><td>AssetId</td><td>ClientId</td><td>DateOfStatement</td><td>InvestmentType</td><td>Category</td><td>Isin</td><td>IsinDescription</td><td>IsinCurrency</td><td>TradingVenue</td><td>ShareHolding</td><td>TotalIssuedShares</td><td>Notes</td><td>IsCurrent</td><td>DateTo</td><td>DateFrom</td><td>LastModified</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>test</td><td>15.12.2021 23:32:07</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>True</td><td>15.12.2021 23:32:07</td><td>15.12.2021 23:32:07</td><td>15.12.2021 23:32:07</td></tr></table>"
try{
    table =TMDIWebApiController.GetAssets()
}
catch{
    console.error('Unable to get HTML data from webapi');
    console.error('Passing the string into view is working');
    table = string;
}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Anuj Bajpai Thank you gor your help how i  can get the data from the web api
I i try something like this  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h2> Data</h2>
    <div id="demo">@TMDIWebApiController.GetAssets() </div>
  D
</body>
My view does not show  me  as table but as jtml script

Comment: use innerHTML insted of innerText